Cannot import Pandas in Visual Studio Code
I installed Pandas in Visual Studio Code and checked that it was installed by using pip show pandas in the terminal and it popped up 2.2.2. I also checked that my python version is 3.11.9. I import pandas as pd and use pd.DataFrame function and it didnot appear any error. But when I run the code, it showed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\ProgrammingCode\Python\PYROBOT\pyrobot\robot.py", line 1, in 
import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
(myenv) (butterfly) D:\ProgrammingCode\Python\PYROBOT>pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 2.2.2
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author:
Author-email: The Pandas Development Team pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD 3-Clause License
I have been trying to deal with this problem for over 3 days with all ways and methods but cannot fix it. I don't know if there are some problems that exist in my Window Paths?

You probably don't use the same python version to install modules and to run your script

Your vs code interpreter might not be same with you virtual env python interpreter to ensure that  please run
which python3

on your terminal
then use command palete on your vscode with ctrl+shit+p then type select python interpreter. If interpreter location is diffrent than your which python3 result it might be the cause
